# Solubility in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of two related systems

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime, and let $u_1, u_2, u_3$ be squarefree integers not divisible by $p$, with the product $u_1 u_2 u_3$ a square. Let $c_1, c_2, c_3$ be integers not divisible by $p$.

I want to show that the system
$$ u_1 y_1^2 = x - pc_1 $$
$$ u_2 y_2^2 = x - pc_2 $$
$$ u_3 y_3^2 = x - pc_3 $$
has a solution $(x, y_1, y_2, y_3)$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$
if the other system
$$ u_1 a_1^2 + pb_1^2 = 1 $$
$$ u_2 a_2^2 + pb_2^2 = 1 $$
has solutions $(a_1, b_1)$ and $(a_2, b_2)$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

---

Context: I'm reading this paper by Sir Swinnerton-Dyer and he makes this statement and I'm trying to fill in the details. Paper: [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a438/0515d897cb4b93890665eb9a8e140cc173f2.pdf?_ga=2.76261778.662198196.1596011990-1726846971.1596011990)

On page 521: "Let $\mathbf{u} = (u_1, u_2, u_3)$ be in $U_\mathcal{B}$ and let $p$ be a prime dividing $b$. If the $u_i$ are all units at $p$, the condition that the $2$-covering associated with $\mathbf{u}$ should be locally soluble at $p$ is
$$ \chi_p(u_1) = \chi_p(u_2) = 0 $$."

The relevant $2$-covering associated with a triple $(m_1, m_2, m_3)$ (which WLOG can assume $m_i$ squarefree) is the system of equations
$$ m_1 y_1^2 = x - bc_1 $$
$$ m_2 y_2^2 = x - bc_2 $$
$$ m_3 y_3^2 = x - bc_3 $$
I think WLOG, one can assume that $b$ and $c_i$ have no common factors.

Also, the author defined
$$ \chi_p(u) = (u, p)_p $$
where $(u, v)_p$ is the additive Hilbert symbol
$$ (u, v)_p = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } ux^2 + vy^2 = 1 \text{ is soluble in } \mathbb{Q}_p \\
1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: "this paper"...?

Comment: Is there nothing about $u_3$ in the second system? -- It seems to me that those have solutions iff $u_i$ is a square or $p$ times a square in $\mathbb Q_p$. -- The whole thing looks as if one should express it with quadratic forms.

Comment: @TokenToucan I have put a link to the paper in the question!

Comment: Nothing was mentioned about $u_3$, which is really weird to me. However, there is a condition that $u_1 u_2 u_3$ is square, which I have edited to include.

Comment: It looks like you are using $p$ for $b$, which is a *substantial* typo if that's the case. I see nothing in the paper that looks like the 2nd system. It might be helpful (at least to me :)) if you more carefully connected your question with the paper.

Comment: Well at least $u_1u_2u_3$ being a square solves that issue: From the definition and additivity of that Hilbert symbol (bottom p. 517) it then follows that if $(u_1, p)_p = (u_2,p)_p=0$ then also $(u_3, p)_p=0$. @TokenToucan: The "second system" then is eq. (13) in the paper. I for my part cannot find the "first system" though ...

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg The first one is eqn (4), page 4 of the pdf - but it uses rather different notation, and while I am pretty sure it is the right thing, the $p$ vs $b$ makes me wonder that I'm not thinking right...

Comment: @TokenToucan: I see, and I share your confusion about that then.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. Let me copy from the paper so to minimize any differences.

Comment: The 'first system' is equation (4), where instead the $m_i$ has been replaced with $u_i$.  But the RHS $x - bc_i$ I re-wrote as $x - p (b/p)c_i = x - pc'_i$. And then relabelled the $c_i'$ to $c_i$. I thought this would simplify things because the $b$ is squarefree and it would make the 'first system' slightly more similar to the 'second system'

Comment: Again, super sorry for all the confusion caused...>.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample: $p=2, u_1:=u_2:=-1, u_3:=1, c_1:=1, c_2:=c_3:=5$.

Namely, the "second system" is now solved by $a_i=b_i=1$, but if there existed $x, y_i$ which solve the first system, the second and third equation of that first system would imply that $y_2=y_3=0$ (because $-1$ is not a square in $\mathbb Q_2$), a fortiori $x=5p=10$. But then the first equation of the first system would read $-y_1^2=8$ which is not true for any $y_1 \in \mathbb Q_2$.

---

I am pretty sure that for all $p\neq 2$, the second system and $p \nmid u_i$ force all $u_i$ to be squares in $\mathbb Q_p$, relying on the crucial fact that there, all elements of $1+p\mathbb Z_p$ are squares. This in turn makes the first system easily solvable, but then the whole approach seems like overkill. Also, in the case $p=2$, the conditions almost still force all $u_i$ to be squares, but there is this accidental extra solution of $u=-1$ which led me to the above counterexample.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply (been very busy writing a report over the last week), but thank you for this answer! It helped a lot to clear up some things for me.

Comment: Can I just clarify some stuff: so for $p\neq 2$, we have that $1 - pb_i$ is a square in $\mathbb{Q}_p$, and hence $\sqrt{u_i}$ exists. Then for the first system, set $x=1$, and then we have $(\sqrt{u_i} y_i)^2 = 1 - pc_i$, and the RHS is a square again, and so one can solve the 3 equations to find $y_1, y_2, y_3$ by $y_i = \sqrt{1 - pc_i} / \sqrt{u_i}$. Is this right? The fact you stated that "$1 + p \mathbb{Z}_p$ are all squares" is super useful too!

Comment: For the 'overkill' part, later on the author proceeds to convert a whole bunch of p-adic conditions into 'being in the kernel of a certain matrix', so I guess thats why this portion was necessary.

Comment: For the $p = 2$ case, I think the arguments in the paper will proceed fine even with avoiding the prime $p=2$, but that is a nice counter example too!